# Compile a whole Folder with tex files using python

Tags: python, latex, pdflatex

how to compile a folder which content of latex files.
I would try to use python to compile the whole folder.

In the past I use the Terminal to compile the folders

```
for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i;done
```

but I rather use Python

Comment: Why not just use the terminal like you have been doing?

Comment: I do my whole work on Python, and that helps me out to manage everything from two programs instead of multiples

Comment: To me, using the shell script (like you have done so far) sounds more reasonable.

Comment: Is it very different with python???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any good pdflatex bindings in python, but you could just use subprocess.

```py
import subprocess
import glob

for path in glob.iglob('*.tex'):
    subprocess.run(['pdflatex', path])
```

If you want to be able to use this from the command line and pass any directory path to it, you can do something like `for path in glob.iglob(os.path.join(sys.argv[1], '*.tex')):` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, but where I should write the path. For example I have a lot of tex files in C:/Document/Latex. which is not in a subfolder.